# Get a list of all python users with the Github API using the Java language

Tags: javascript, java, android, python, github-api

it's the first time I try to use the Github API V3 and I was wondering how can I get a list of users that use a particular technology.

I could see that over the API it's possible to get a list like this:

https://api.github.com/search/users?q=python&page=2&per_page=25

The issue is when I try to use java to make the same call to the API.

```
    RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService(client);
        searchQuery.put("keyword","python");
        searchQuery.put("page","1");
        searchQuery.put("per_page","10");
    List<SearchRepository> searchRes = null;
        searchRes = service.searchRepositories(searchQuery);
```

This simply doesn't work. I don't find anywhere in the API for java how to get a list of users, paginate and get information about every user afterwards.

Can anyone give me a clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `"keyword"` should you put `"q"`?

Comment: Nope. I tried that too.

Comment: Why is javascript tagged? And python?